# User role list in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

[image]

```py
    rlist = []
    for role in user.roles:
        if role.name != "@everyone":
            rlist.append(role.mention)
        else:
            rlist.append("No roles")
```

currently im creating a list for the users roles in that server but my output is always No roles | Roles here and when no roles is true it works but how can i make it not say no roles when there are user roles

This is my entire code

```py
@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.user)
async def whois(ctx, *, user: discord.Member = None):
    guild = ctx.guild
    if user == None:
        user = ctx.author

    rlist = []
    for role in user.roles:
        if role.name != "@everyone":
            rlist.append(role.mention)
        else:
            rlist.append("No roles")

    b = " | ".join(rlist)

    badgelist = ""

    if user.public_flags.hypesquad_brilliance:
        badgelist += f"Hypesquad Brilliance <:brillance:958385039870136361>\n"
    elif user.public_flags.hypesquad_bravery:
        badgelist += f"Hypesquad Bravery <:bravery:958384913344786463>\n"
    elif user.public_flags.hypesquad_balance:
        badgelist += f"Hypesquad Balance <:balance:958384787951857744>\n"
    else:
        badgelist += f"No badges\n"

    embed = discord.Embed(timestamp=ctx.message.created_at, color=0x2F3136)
    embed.set_author(name=user, icon_url=user.avatar_url)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar_url)
    embed.add_field(name=f" Display Name:", value=f"{user.mention}")
    embed.add_field(name=f"<:Hypesquad:958382023028928532> Badges:", value=badgelist, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name=f"Avatar", value=f"[Avatar link]({user.avatar_url})")
    embed.add_field(name=f'<:settings:958374936605499452> Created Account on:',value=user.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"),inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name=f'<:joined_at:958375038971699200> Joined {guild.name} on:',value=user.joined_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"),inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name=f'<:mention:958374345812627467> Roles:',value=''.join([b]),inline=False)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"ID: {user.id}")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: What is the expected output when a user has the role `@everyone`? Why do you think this adds `No roles`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is a bit off from your requirement; at its core what you’re doing currently is effectively replacing the `@everyone` role with an entry in the list that says `No roles`, regardless of whether or not there actually are indeed no roles associated with that user.

What it seems you *should* do instead is `continue` and not take any action if the role you’re currently operating on in the loop is `@everyone`, while also adding a logic gate to discern when there are truly “no roles” (aka only the `@everyone` role, it seems):

```
rlist = []
if len(user.roles) <= 1:
    rlist.append("No roles")
else:
    for role in user.roles:
        if role.name != "@everyone":
            rlist.append(role.mention)
```